# xslt regular expressions

Tags: regex, xslt

more problems with processing nessus xml files.

I have some xml data from nessus that stores information such as host names etc in xml tags that can be extracted using this xsl tag:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../ReportItem[(@pluginID=12053)]/description"/>
```

Then only problem is this tag stores it with a bunch of garbage in it besides the host name.  For example, the tag usually has this information in it:

> Synopsis : It is possible to obtain the network name of the remote
>   host. Description : The remote host listens on UDP port 137 or TCP
>   port 445 and replies to NetBIOS nbtscan or SMB requests. Note that
>   this plugin gathers information to be used in other plugins but does
>   not itself generate a report. Solution : n/a Risk factor : None Plugin
>   output : The following 6 NetBIOS names have been gathered : VOODOO1 =
>   Computer name VOODOO = Workgroup / Domain name VOODOO1 = File Server
>   Service VOODOO = Browser Service Elections VOODOO = Master Browser
>   **MSBROWSE** = Master Browser The remote host has the following MAC address on its adapter : 10:50:56:ab:10:02

The only part I'm interested in is the part "VOODOO1 = Computer name".  Actually whats before the '=' sign to be more precise.  I was wondering if it was possible to have a regular expression function within the 'select' for the tag, something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="regexp(../ReportItem[(@pluginID=12053)]/description,'\w =')"/>
```

That would extract the only the contents of the tag that matches the regular expression and display it.  Right now I have the whole contents of the tag display which is annoying.  I have tried to use various variations of

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$elValue" regex="\w = ">
```

tags with no luck.  I keep getting errors saying 'cant be subtag of `<td>` or any other xslt element I have tried, ie for-each etc.

Thanks in advance.

Based on feedback so far, here is some of the xml that's generated by nessus

```
<ReportItem port="137" svc_name="netbios-ns?" protocol="udp" severity="1"     pluginID="10150" pluginName="Windows NetBIOS / SMB Remote Host Information Disclosure" pluginFamily="Windows">
<description>Synopsis :

It is possible to obtain the network name of the remote host.

Description :

The remote host listens on UDP port 137 or TCP port 445 and replies to NetBIOS nbtscan or SMB requests. 

Note that this plugin gathers information to be used in other plugins but does not itself generate a report.

Solution :

n/a

Risk factor :

None

Plugin output :
The following 6 NetBIOS names have been gathered :

 VOODOO1       = Computer name  VOODOO              = Workgroup / Domain name     VOODOO1       = File Server Service  VOODOO              = Browser Service Elections     VOODOO              = Master Browser
 __MSBROWSE__     = Master Browser

The remote host has the following MAC address on its adapter :
   01:a0:52:bf:0a:02

</description>
</ReportItem>`
```

`<xsl:value-of select="regexp(../ReportItem[(@pluginID=12053)]/description,'\w =')"/>`  This line doesn't really work.  I made it up to see if anyone knew if there was something similar to it.  It only generates an error because I made it up.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? If 1.0, what engine?

Comment: Are you saying that the value-of instruction is emitting "VOODOO1 = Computer name VOODOO = Workgroup / Domain name..." or does the value-of instruction you posted not work at all?  It would be helpful if you add concrete example of the input XML, what you're currently getting (if anything), and what you want.

Comment: Of Course here is an example of the xml.  This is generated from nessus.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say the xml was added to original post.  The xml line I proposed doesn't work because I made it up as an idea of what I thought may be possible if someone was familiar with it.  In general, I'm trying to use regex to filter something and return it back to me in a select if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need XSLT 2.0 for this. I suspect the error messages you were getting with xsl:analyze-string were because you were using an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: I'm using windows powershell to use the .net xml objects.  The error message seems to indicate that it recognizes the xsl command but doesn't want it as a subtag of anything I put it under.  The other examples I see of it's usage show that it can be a subtag of the tags I were using.  Do you know if it's possible to carry out the regex on the select xpath results?

Comment: Microsoft processors only implement 1.0. If you want to move forward to more recent XML technologies, you need to start thinking about third-party solutions, of which there is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Kay noted this won't work with XSLT 1.0. Get the .NET version of [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml) so you can use a more modern version of XSLT. You can call it from the command line or Powershell.  Here is a sample to get you started:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">  
    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="."
            regex="(\w+)\s+=\s*Computer name">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```